# Unresolved external symbol error (LNK2019)

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, odbc

Following on from this question:  [Getting list of available ODBC data sources in my Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021280/)

When I compile the code in the answer I get an "unresolved external symbol" error.

In my MainWindow I have hadded the following includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlucode.h>
```

and have created a function like so:

```
int listDataSources()
{
    // Get an Environment handle
    SQLHENV hEnv = SQL_NULL_HENV;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);

    if( ! SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret) ) {}

    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors reported area:

[image: image showing errors]

The sql.h file in use has the following section:

[image: image of sql.h code]

This is definitely the file being used and ODBCVER is greater than 0x0300 as if I place a #define MIKEDIDTHIS = 777 after the ODBCVER test it gets set and I can dDebug() it.

ODBCVER is set ealrier in the file with this code:

```
#ifndef ODBCVER
#define ODBCVER 0x0380
#endif
```

I'm using Qt Creator version 3.4.2 and Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013 32 bit)

Can you walk me through the steps I should take in trying to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: You have a linker error. That is something totally different than a compiler error. Usually the compilation was executed successfully before you can even receive a linker error.

Comment: @Bowdzone Thank you.  Am I right in thinking its a link from the sql.h file that is missing?   And if so, what should it be linked to, and where?

Comment: @NathanOliver  I have changed the question somewhat - I have looked at the answer you linked to, but even having read that, I still don't know how to resolve my issue.  So I've asked for help to walk me through the steps I need to take.

Comment: @Michael Vincent: I tested it with the QTCreator, you need to link against odbc32.lib. For me, this works by adding a line like this to the .pro file: 
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" -lodbc32
No idea why I do not have to specify this lib if I link things together using visual studio.
Also no idea if you need to install some additional stuff to get this "Microsoft SDK".

Comment: @erg Thank you for testing with QTCreator.  My lib file was in a different location ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86 ), but other than that it seems to work - at least an exe is created and runs and, most importantly, produces a list of the data sources on my pc.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Michael: Your welcome. I was wrong, also the visual studio projects links against odbc32.lib (had made no sense at all if there would have been no need to link).
I just looked at the wrong entry in the still-not-so-handy visual studio settings dialog.